# Handling Future[WSResponse] in play controller

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have a play Controller end point I want to write that will invoke a service method. The service method returns `Future[WSResponse]`. I do not want my controller to do anything but just relay this WSResponse to the client. How do I do this? `Action.async` signature does not allow it. This is in scala

Comment: what type of response you want to relay? You can use map function to cast it to Future[Result]

Comment: Are you trying to write a proxy here?

Comment: @Tomer, you are kind of right. I am doing that here partly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to add some more details to your question. a code snippet will be helful. but I will try with the basics:)

```
def foo(url: String) = Action.async {
  WS.url(url).get().map(resp => Ok(resp.body))
}
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: This has a problem. You are assuming WS has the response as 200. It might not always be the case